# directory access permission seemingly inconsistent

Tags: permissions, users, access-control

I want to grant new users access to a directory owned by root. "ls -lt" returns

```
drw-rw-rw- 74 root        root               4096 Mar 21 20:51 dirname
```

My old user can cd into it. However, when I create new users, and put them in the same groups as my old user, they remain unable to access it via cd (they can, however, use "sudo -i" and then navigate into it as *root*, but this is clearly not ideal).

Am I missing something? Is there some other element to access permissions beyond what's printed by "ls -lt"?

To be clear, my question is: How can I grant the new users access to this directory *without* changing the owner of the directory? Since the current state of the directory doesn't seem to stop my old users from entering, I assume what I'm missing is something regarding the new users, not the directory itself.

UPDATE: It looks like one of the new users on my machine went ahead and used chmod to just add x to the rights; this "fixed" things, but also renders me unable to dig for an explanation about what was happening. I'm leaving the question in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Non-root users can't `cd` into a directory which isn't executable:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir test
$ ls -ld test
drwxr-xr-x 2 username users 40 Mar 22 17:10 test
$ chmod a-x test
$ cd test
bash: cd: test: Permission denied
```

The problem must be something else.

Comment: There's one exception to this: as usual, `root` (or any user with UID 0) can bypass this restriction.

Comment: Strange: my old user (the one with access) is neither root nor UID 0. Is it possible that the permissions exist in more than one place (and perhaps came out of sync, such that one of them is executable)?

Comment: @mwarrior Not unless this was a network mounted filesystem.